# Can Kumagami in Charlotte possess Yuu Otosaka?

Tags: charlotte

So since Yuu looted all abilities, including Yusa's of course, does that mean he can be possessed by someone just like her? And if so, can that person be Kumagami?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seeing that Yusa's power is [Spiritism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritism), she can be a medium for the dead. Which is also mentioned in the [wikia](http://charlotte.wikia.com/wiki/Yusa_Nishimori).

> Yusa has the ability of Spiritism. She is understood to be a medium,
>   seemingly capable of channeling and/or conversing with the dead.

So it is not entirely impossible so long as they have a way to communicate with Kumogami's soul.